# Get notification channel (or notification settings) for other app

Tags: java, android, kotlin, service, android-notifications

I have a [`NotificationListenerService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService) and I'd like to get each notification's [`NotificationChannel`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel).

NotificationListenerService provides a function, `getNotificationChannels` which requires a [`UserHandle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserHandle) with access to notifications.

**What do I need to do to get a UserHandle with the correct permissions? Using `Process.myUserHandle()` throws a SecurityException.**

I cannot use [`NotificationManager.getNotificationChannel`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#getNotificationChannel(java.lang.String)) because the NotificationChannel was not created by my app.

Alternatively, is there a different way to get the sound and vibration settings for a [`StatusBarNotification`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/StatusBarNotification)?

Comment: It appears there is no way of accessing a NotificationChannel. Even if you could access it, notifications from older apps (before API level 26) don't have a channel ID, so it would be of no use. They just broke the API.

The only way of getting any extra data is [Notification.extras](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification#extras).